# How do i fix my while loop

Tags: python

I am writing a program that asks the user to enter a password. If the password matches the constant I've set it prints out a "successfully logged in message". However if the password is incorrect, it gives the number of guesses left and asks the user to try again. The program should end after 3 incorrect guesses but it keeps on asking even after 3 attempts have been used. I think the problem is in my while loop but I am unsure.

Code:

```
def main():
    PASSWORD = "apple"
    ALLOWED = 3

    password = input("Enter the password: ")
    while password != PASSWORD :
        ALLOWED = ALLOWED - 1
        print("Wrong. You have", ALLOWED, "guesses left")

        if ALLOWED == 0:
                    print("You have been locked out")
        password = input("Enter again ")            


    print("You have successfully logged into the system")



main()
```

Comment: you're not breaking out of the loop when there are no ALLOWED attempts left

Comment: Also, use `raw_input` in place of `input`

Comment: @zengr Maybe it's Python 3

Answer (score 3):

Right now you never exit your while loop. To break out of it, use the `break` keyword.
To exit your program completely, you will need to `import sys` and `sys.exit()`
I suggest adding these to your `if ALLOWED == 0` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `break` to exit the loop, or add a secondary condition, otherwise it will keep going anyway until the password is correct.

So, either:

```
while (password != PASSWORD) and (ALLOWED > 0):
```

Or:

```
    if ALLOWED == 0:
                print("You have been locked out")
                break
```

Comment: `break`ing out or adding the test will still have it say "you're logged in", because the next line after the loop says `"You have successfully logged into the system"`. You need to exit the function, not just the loop.

Comment: Ah, that is true. I kind of didn't really focus on things beyond fixing the immediate problem; My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The condition password != PASSWORD is not enough to exit the loop (It will exit the loop only if you give the right password). Add the condition also in while (password != PASSWORD and ALLOWED > 0)

Answer (score 0):

Change `print("You have been locked out")` to `sys.exit("You have been locked out")` (or otherwise exit the `main`). Remember to `import sys` to use `sys.exit`.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop requires a correct password to finish, and there is no other way to exit the loop. I suggest a break statement:

```
def main():
    PASSWORD = "apple"
    ALLOWED = 3

    password = input("Enter the password: ")
    while password != PASSWORD :
        ALLOWED = ALLOWED - 1
        print("Wrong. You have", ALLOWED, "guesses left")

        if ALLOWED == 0:
            print("You have been locked out")
            break
        password = input("Enter again ")

    print("You have successfully logged into the system")
```

You may want to do more research if your program needs to be secure.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work but just making it check if ALLOWED == 0 and if it does print "you are locked out", and if ALLOWED <= 0 then it will not let you go any further.

```
def main():
    PASSWORD = "apple"
    ALLOWED = 3

    password = input("Enter the password: ")
    while password != PASSWORD or ALLOWED <= 0:
        ALLOWED = ALLOWED - 1
        if ALLOWED > 0: print("Wrong. You have", ALLOWED, "guesses left")
        if ALLOWED == 0: print("You have been locked out") 
        if ALLOWED < 0:
                    print("You have been locked out")
        password = input("Enter again ")            


    print("You have successfully logged into the system")



main()
```

also wrote a different version which seemed easier in my opinion

```
def main():

    USERNAME = "admin"
    PASSWORD = "root"
    ATTEMPTS = 3
    while ATTEMPTS >= 1:
        print("You have",ATTEMPTS,"attempts left")
        if ATTEMPTS == 0:
            break
        user = input("Please enter your username:")
        password = input("Now enter your password:")
        if user == USERNAME and password == PASSWORD:
            print("\nYou have successfully logged into the system")
            return
        else:
            print("\nThis user name or password does not exist\n")
            ATTEMPTS -= 1
    print("you have been locked out.")

main()
```